# C++ Returning and Using a Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Lets say for example I have a function like so, that is meant to return a pointer to an array.

```
int*   oddInRange(int low, int high){
int odds[someLength];
// Some code to fill the array.

return *odds; // Is this the correct way to return?
}
```

Then once I've returned the pointer. How would I use it and get values from it?

```
int* testOdds = oddsInRange(1,10);
// What do I need to do with testOdds to get the values
// that were generated in the function above?
```

I understand that I probably don't need to use pointers here, but this it for the purposes of learning.

Comment: Even if you would correctly return like `return odds;` the array is gone after the function ends.

Comment: Have you tried it?  A quick trip over to ideone.com would show you that this doesn't even compile.  You'll get :error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'"  *odds is an int. not a pointer to an int

Answer (score 2):

```
 return *odds;
```

is an error since `*odds` evaluates to `int`, which does not match the return type. You can fix the syntax error by using

```
 return odds;
```

but that will lead to problems at run time since the pointer will be invalid as soon as the function returns.

It's better to use `std::vector` and avoid all the problems with arrays.

```
std::vector<int>  oddInRange(int low, int high){
   std::vector<int> odds(someLength);

   // Some code to fill the array.

   return odds;
}
```

Comment: return *adds is perfectly valid syntax.  It's a type conversion error

Answer (score 1):

This will not work; your array is allocated on the stack, and as such is not available after the function exits.

In your case, you need to do one of two things - either create an array from the caller and pass it in, or dynamically allocate an array and return it. Take this as an example which dynamically allocates the array:

```
int*   oddInRange(int low, int high){
    int* odds = malloc(sizeof(int) * someLength);
    // Some code to fill the array.

    return odds; // Is this the correct way to return?
}
```

Or fills it in:

```
void oddInRange(int* odds, int low, int high) {
    // Do stuff to odds
}

// And to call...
int* myArr = malloc(sizeof(int) * someLength);
oddInRange(myArr, 1, 2);
```

Anyway, if we ignore the stack allocation problem for a second, your code is still wrong. You want to get a pointer to the array. In C, an array variable can decay to a pointer implicitly, so you don't need to use `&` or `*` to get a pointer to the array, you just use the name. You could also take the address of the first element. Take these examples:

```
int myArray[10];
int* myArrayPtr = *myArray; // What you had. Incorrect.
int* myArrayPtr = myArray;  // OK - arrays decay to pointers to the first element.
int* myArrayPtr = &myArray[0]; // Also OK.
```

Comment: I did:

int* odds = malloc(sizeof(int) * oddCount);

and got error:

cannot initialize a variable of type "int *" with a r value of type "void *"

After that line I am setting the values of the array as you normally would.

Comment: Oh wait, C++, you should use `new` instead of `malloc`